# Simplifying trigonometric and cyclometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

could anyone show me the steps, to reducing this expression: $
\cos(\cot^{-1}{x})
$ so it doesn't contain any trigonometric or cyclometric (inverse trigonometric) functions?

Thanks

Comment: Draw a right-angled triangle, with the two shorter sides be $1$ and $x$.

Comment: Added an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on [the convention of the range of $\cot^{-1}$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseCotangent.html), the answer can be slightly different, but the reasoning is analogous. If the range of $\cot^{-1}$ is taken to be $(-\frac{\pi}2,0)\cup(0,\frac{\pi}2]$, then consider a point $A$ on a 2D-plane which coordinates are
$$A=\cases{\left(|x|, 1\right)&\text{if }x\ge 0\\
\left(|x|, -1\right)&\text{if }x<0}$$

then $\cot^{-1}x$ is the angle measured from positive $x$-axis to segment $OA$. The cosine of this angle is therefore
$$\cos\left(\cot^{-1} x\right) = \frac{|x|}{\sqrt{|x|^2+1^2}} = \frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

Alternatively, if the range of $\cot^{-1}$ is taken to be $(0,\pi)$, the answer is different as $\cot^{-1}x$ is in different possible quadrants.